# VBA Copy data list with variable length

Tags: excel, vba

So what i am trying to do is copy a data list to another location (eventually to another tab but i can figure that out myself). The data list is variable in length but it is filled into another cell manually.

- List that needs to be copied is 2 rows wide (H & I) and x columns long (from row 2 to "end")
- The value in cell N6 is the amount of rows
- So the range that needs to be copied is H2 to I(amount of rows +1)

Here is my code

```
Sub Copycells()
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim wb1 As Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Long

Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set wb1 = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")


'check data for list length

LastRow = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(6, "N").Value + 1


'copy data
Range("V2:W?").Copy Range("H2:I?")

End Sub
```

So where i'm struggling is how to fill in the range for the copy, in a sense combining the row letter with the variable number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you might have mistaken columns for rows and rows for columns in the explanation, that you give in your question.

However, I'm fairly sure i understand what you want the code to do.
Try this:

```
Sub Copycells()
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim wb1 As Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Long

Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set wb1 = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")

'check data for list length

LastRow = Range("N6").Value + 1

'copy data
Range("H2:I" & LastRow).Copy
End Sub
```

You need to specify where the copied list needs to be pasted, but I'll let you have a try on that on your own.

Comment: Oh yes - I placed a `"` wrongly - i have edited my answer so that it should work.